# Perspective Transform OpenCV

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing

I'm new to OpenCV on Android and try to do Perspective Transform but I don't know how to use getperspectivetransform() and warpperspective() functions.I could detect rectangle from an image, but don't know how to warp.

Here is the detect rectangle function:

```
 Mat tempMat = new Mat();
        Mat src = new Mat();
        Utils.bitmapToMat(image, tempMat);

        Imgproc.cvtColor(tempMat, src, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2RGB);

        Mat blurred = src.clone();
        Imgproc.medianBlur(src, blurred, 9);

        Mat gray0 = new Mat(blurred.size(), CvType.CV_8U), gray = new Mat();

        List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();

        List<Mat> blurredChannel = new ArrayList<Mat>();
        blurredChannel.add(blurred);
        List<Mat> gray0Channel = new ArrayList<Mat>();
        gray0Channel.add(gray0);

        MatOfPoint2f approxCurve = new MatOfPoint2f();

        double maxArea = 0;
        int maxId = -1;

        for (int c = 0; c < 3; c++) {
            int ch[] = { c, 0 };
            Core.mixChannels(blurredChannel, gray0Channel, new MatOfInt(ch));

            int thresholdLevel = 1;
            for (int t = 0; t < thresholdLevel; t++) {
                if (t == 0) {
                    Imgproc.Canny(gray0, gray, 50, 50, 3, true); // true ?
                    Imgproc.dilate(gray, gray, new Mat(), new Point(-1, -1), 1); // 1
                    // ?
                } else {
                    Imgproc.adaptiveThreshold(gray0, gray, thresholdLevel,
                            Imgproc.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,
                            Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY,
                            (src.width() + src.height()) / 200, t);
                }

                Imgproc.findContours(gray, contours, new Mat(),
                        Imgproc.RETR_LIST, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

                for (MatOfPoint contour : contours) {
                    MatOfPoint2f temp = new MatOfPoint2f(contour.toArray());

                    double area = Imgproc.contourArea(contour);
                    approxCurve = new MatOfPoint2f();
                    Imgproc.approxPolyDP(temp, approxCurve,
                            Imgproc.arcLength(temp, true) * 0.02, true);

                    if (approxCurve.total() == 4 && area >= maxArea) {
                        double maxCosine = 0;

                        List<Point> curves = approxCurve.toList();
                        for (int j = 2; j < 5; j++) {

                            double cosine = Math.abs(angle(curves.get(j % 4),
                                    curves.get(j - 2), curves.get(j - 1)));
                            maxCosine = Math.max(maxCosine, cosine);
                        }

                        if (maxCosine < 0.45) {
                            maxArea = area;
                            maxId = contours.indexOf(contour);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I draw rectangle with this statement.

```
if (maxId >= 0) {
            Rect rect = Imgproc.boundingRect(contours.get(maxId));

            Imgproc.rectangle(src, rect.tl(), rect.br(), new Scalar(255, 0, 0,
                    .8), 4);

        }
```

After that I convert mat to bitmap and show on an imageview.

[Here is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZ5Wu.jpg)

So my problem is warpping, How can I warp the rectangle and rotate it?

and If it is possible, how can I improve detecting rectangle? Any hints?

(OpenCV Android SDK Ver: 3.41, Android Studio Ver: 3.01)

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to warp the detected contour into rectangle,

1. Get the contours of the rectangle
2. find convex hull of the contour
3. Using approxPolyDP reduce the convex hull points into 4 points
4. fit line to consecutive points (ex, if pts is the array, lines are fit as follows l1 = line Between(pts[0], pts[1]), l2 = line Between(pts[1], pts[2]),  l3 = line Between(pts[2], pts[3]), l4 = lineBetween(pts[3], pts[0])
5. find the intersection between these lines, you'll end up with four points
6. Order the points in clockwise order (inputCorners = TopLeft, TopRight, BottomRight, BottomLeft)
7. create an output image with needed resolution and make the corner points in the same clockwise order ((0,0), (0, cols), (rows, cols), (rows, 0))
8. find homography using the function

   ```
   Mat homography = Calib3d.findHomography(inputCorners, imageCorners, Calib3d.RANSAC, 10);
   ```
9. using the output homography matrix, warp the input image using the function

   ```
   Imgproc.warpPerspective(image, outputMat, homography, new Size(image.cols(), image.rows()));
   ```

you can refer to the following [link](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/09/01/build-kick-ass-mobile-document-scanner-just-5-minutes/)

Answer (score 0):

This is my kotlin extensin version you can use it in your projects.

```
fun Bitmap.perspectiveTransform(srcPoints: List<org.opencv.core.Point>) : 
    Bitmap{
     val dstWidth = max(
        srcPoints[0].distanceFrom(srcPoints[1]),
        srcPoints[2].distanceFrom(srcPoints[3])
     )
     val dstHeight = max(
         srcPoints[0].distanceFrom(srcPoints[2]),
         srcPoints[1].distanceFrom(srcPoints[3])
      )

    val dstPoints: List<org.opencv.core.Point> = listOf(
       org.opencv.core.Point(0.0, 0.0),
       org.opencv.core.Point(dstWidth, 0.0),
       org.opencv.core.Point(0.0, dstHeight),
       org.opencv.core.Point(dstWidth, dstHeight)
    )
    return try {
         val srcMat = Converters.vector_Point2d_to_Mat(srcPoints)
         val dstMat = Converters.vector_Point2d_to_Mat(dstPoints)
         val perspectiveTransformation = 
    Imgproc.getPerspectiveTransform(srcMat, dstMat)
    val inputMat = Mat(this.height, this.width, CvType.CV_8UC1)
    Utils.bitmapToMat(this, inputMat)
    val outPutMat = Mat(dstHeight.toInt(), dstWidth.toInt(), CvType.CV_8UC1)
    Imgproc.warpPerspective(
        inputMat,
        outPutMat,
        perspectiveTransformation,
        Size(dstWidth, dstHeight)
    )
    val outPut = Bitmap.createBitmap(
        dstWidth.toInt(),
        dstHeight.toInt(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565
    )
    //Imgproc.cvtColor(outPutMat , outPutMat , Imgproc.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
    Utils.matToBitmap(outPutMat , outPut)
    outPut
  }
  catch ( e : Exception){
    e.printStackTrace()
    this
  }
}
```

To use distance from I write another extension function

```
fun org.opencv.core.Point.distanceFrom(srcPoint: org.opencv.core.Point): 
     Double {
     val w1 = this.x - srcPoint.x
     val h1 = this.y - srcPoint.y
     val distance = w1.pow(2) + h1.pow(2)
     return sqrt(distance)
   }
```

Also in this answer the correct src Points indices are :
0 : topleft

1 : topRight

2 : bottomLeft

3 : bottomRight

Good luck